# C# default value in constructor same as two constructors for serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, constructor, default-value

When I provide a constructor with a default value

```
  public MyClass(string description = null) { .... }
```

is this equivalent to

```
  public MyClass() { .... }
  public MyClass(string description) { .... }
```

in terms of **Serialization**. In other words, is a **default constructor available**? Practically it is, but will I face some issues when I use serialization?

Comment: It also depends on the serializer. Many serializers ***don't need*** constructors. Any constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  It unfortunately is not a default constructor.

When you write:

```
public MyClass(string description = null) { .... }
```

You're actually making a constructor that accepts a string parameter, but has an attribute marking the default value for that attribute.  This is different than having a default constructor on the class.

Comment: exactly. optional parameters are just a compiler trick. They only affect the CALLER, so that if the caller omits the parameter, the compiler uses the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have problems in that case.

I've tried to call a constructor described by you via reflection, and it thrown TargetInvokationException: (Argument count mismatch).